# PowerShell Script to populate a ListBox with Primary Devices from System Control Configuration Manager (SCCM)

Tags: powershell, active-directory, sccm

I am trying to make a GUI PowerShell Script to populate the ListBox with Primary Devices (ResourceNames) of the user. I have a dropdown list which shows different Organizational Unit's from the Active Directory. In that same Dropdown list I would like to show "Primary Devices" of the User, this information will be collected from the SCCM. Since it is a GUI PowerShell Script I would like to show the Primary Device as Number 1 option (Default) in the dropdown list, Also further ahead I am planning to call the Device number of the of the user where they are "Currently Signed in". Till Now I have coded a ListBox and Dropdown list and a search textbox. The Username is called from another PowerShell Script and it is stored in $username Variable.

The Problem is that ListBox is not getting populated with device numbers from any option selected in the Dropdown List. Please help me figure this out.

```
# Load the System.Web assembly

Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Web"

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Function Get-UserResourceName ($username) {

    $SiteCode = 'FEI'

    Set-Location "$($SiteCode):"

    $userDeviceaffinity = Get-CMUserDeviceAffinity -UserName $username | Select-Object ResourceName

    $userDevice = $userDeviceaffinity | ForEach-Object { $_.PrimaryDevice}

    return $userDevice

}

Function Draw_Main_Form

{

    #Draw the main window

    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

    $Form.Text = "Software Deployment"

    $Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800, 525)

    $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

 

    #SELECT OU LABEL

    $OULabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

    $OULabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 15)

    $OULabel.Text = "Select OU:"

    $OULabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Verdana Pro',10)

    $OULabel.AutoSize = $true

 

    #DROP DOWN LIST

    $ComboBoxOU = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox

    $ComboBoxOU.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 35)

    $ComboBoxOU.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 20)

    $ComboBoxOU.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Verdana Pro',10)

    $ComboBoxOU.DropDownStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle]::DropDownList

 

    #To Show the last OU name in the dropdown list

    foreach ($OU in $OUs) {

        $LastOUName = [regex]::Match($OU, '(?<=OU=)[^,]+').Value 

        $ComboBoxOU.Items.Add($LastOUName)

    }

    $ComboBoxOU.Items.Add("PrimaryDevice")

    $ComboBoxOU.SelectedIndex = 0 #To show the Default OU in the drop down list

 

    #Search Computer Name: Label

    $SearchCompLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label

    $SearchCompLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 70)

    $SearchCompLabel.Text = "Search Computer Name: "

    $SearchCompLabel.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Verdana Pro',10)

    $SearchCompLabel.AutoSize = $true

 

    #Search Box - Computer

    $SearchBoxComp = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

    $SearchBoxComp.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 20)

    $SearchBoxComp.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 90)

    $SearchBoxComp.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Verdana Pro',10)

 

    #List Box Show the list of devices

    $ListBoxComp = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox

    $ListBoxComp.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 300)

    $ListBoxComp.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25, 115)

    $ListBoxComp.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Verdana Pro',10)

    $ListBoxComp.SelectionMode = 'Multiextended'   #Enables multi selection

 

    $script:CompNames = @()  #The CompNames Array is being initialised and $script means that it is accessible from variables outside the fucntions and can be called from anywhere in the script.

   

        function UpdateCompNames {

            $selectedIndex = $ComboBoxOU.SelectedIndex

 

            if ($ComboBoxOU.SelectedItem.ToString() -eq "PrimanyDevice") {

                $script:CompNames = Get-UserResourceName | ForEach-Object { @{ Name = $_ } }

            } else {

                $script:OUCOMP = $OUs[$selectedIndex]

                if ($null -ne $OUCOMP) {

                    $script:CompNames = Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "name=FBC*" -SearchBase $OUCOMP | Sort-Object Name

                } else {

                    $script:CompNames = @()

                }

            }

            UpdateListBox

        }

 

    $ComboBoxOU.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({

        UpdateCompNames

    })
         function UpdateListBox {

            $SearchTextComp = $SearchBoxComp.Text #Allocating the Searched text to the variable

            $WildcardSearchTextComp = "*$SearchTextComp*"

 

            if ($ComboBoxOU.SelectedItem.ToString() -eq "PrimaryDevice") {

                $FileredComps = $CompNames | Where-Object { $_ -like $WildcardSearchTextComp}

            } else {

                $FilteredComps = $CompNames | Where-Object { ($_.Name -like $WildcardSearchTextComp) } #String approximation

            }

            $ListBoxComp.Items.Clear() #refreshing the list

 

            foreach ($FilteredComp in $FilteredComps) {

                if ($ComboBoxOU.SelectedItem.ToString() -eq "PrimaryDevice") {

                    $ListBoxComp.Items.Add($FilteredComp.Name)

                } else {

                    $ListBoxComp.Items.Add($FilteredComp.Name)

                }

            }

        }

    $SearchBoxComp.Add_TextChanged({
        UpdateListBox
    })

    # Update CompNames for the initial population

    UpdateCompNames

    $Form.Controls.AddRange(@($OUlabel,$SearchCompLabel,$ComboBoxOU,$SearchBoxComp,$ListBoxComp))
    #Show the Main Form
    $result = $Form.ShowDialog()

}


# Add OUs to the ComboBox

$OUApp = "OU=System Center,OU=Groups,OU=Electric,DC=corp,DC=local"

$OUs = @(

    "OU=Fresh PXE Workstations,OU=Workstations,OU=Electric,DC=corp,DC=local",

    "OU=laptops,OU=Workstations,OU=Electric,DC=corp,DC=local",

    "OU=Desktops,OU=Workstations,OU=Electric,DC=corp,DC=local"

    "OU=Stale,OU=Workstations,OU=Electric,DC=corp,DC=local"

)

Draw_Main_Form
```